# Having trouble getting my 'Clear' event listener to work properly. Why does it still have the stored values?

Tags: javascript, dom, events

like the title states, the clear button doesn't seem to work the way I'd like it to. The way I envisioned it to function was something like press clear button --> discards all previous values --> displays 0 to start fresh. The function somewhat works, its just that the previous values are still there.

I would like the function to discard all the previous values and allowing the user to input new values. Please help.

```
        <div id="display">
            <div id="previous-display" class="screen">01234</div>
            <div id="current-display" class="screen">0123</div>
        </div>
           
            <div id="clear-keys">
                <button type="button" id="clear">CLEAR</button>
                <button type="button" id="back-space">BKSPCE</button>
            </div>

            <div class="calc-keys"></div>
                <div id="row-one">
                    <button type="button" class="num" id="7" value="7">7</button>
                    <button type="button" class="num" id="8" value="8">8</button>
                    <button type="button" class="num" id="9" value="9">9</button>
                    <button type="button" class="operator" id="add">+</button>
                </div>

                <div id="row-two">
                    <button type="button" class="num" id="4" value="4">4</button>
                    <button type="button" class="num" id="5" value="5">5</button>
                    <button type="button" class="num" id="6"value="6">6</button>
                    <button type="button" class="operator" id="subtract">-</button>
                </div>

                <div id="row-three">
                    <button type="button" class="num" id="1" value="1">1</button>
                    <button type="button" class="num" id="2" value="2">2</button>
                    <button type="button" class="num" id="3" value="3">3</button>
                    <button type="button" class="operator" id="multply">x</button>
                </div>

                <div id="row-four">
                    <button type="button" id="." class="num">.</button>
                    <button type="button" class="num" id="0" value="0">0</button>
                    <button type="button" id="equals">=</button>
                    <button type="button" class="operator" id="division">/</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        let numKeys = document.querySelectorAll('.num');
        let calcScreens = document.querySelectorAll('.screen');
        let currentDisplay = document.getElementById('current-display');
        let previousDisplay = document.getElementById('previous-display');
        let operateNum = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');
        let decimal = document.getElementById('.');
        let clearScreen = document.getElementById('clear');
        let backSpace = document.getElementById('back-space');
        let equalsKey = document.getElementById('equals');

        currentDisplay.textContent = ' ';
        previousDisplay.textContent = ' ';
       
        //calculator functions
        function add(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }
        

        function subtract(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        }

        function multiply(a, b) {
            return a * b;
        }

        function divide(a,b) {
            return a / b;
        }

        function operate(num1, num2, operator) {
            switch (operator) {
                case "+": 
                  return add(num1, num2);
                case "-": 
                  return subtract(num1, num2);
                case "*": 
                  return multiply(num1, num2);
                case "/": 
                  return divide(num1, num2);
            }
        };

        let storedNum = '';
        let selectedOperator = '';
        let firstNum = '';
        let result = '';
        currentDisplay.textContent = 0;

        numKeys.forEach((button) => {
          button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            storedNum += button.id;
            currentDisplay.textContent = storedNum;
         })
       });

        operateNum.forEach((operator => {
            operator.addEventListener('click', function() {
                if (firstNum && storedNum) {
                    displayResult();
                }
                firstNum = storedNum;
                selectedOperator = operator.textContent;
                previousDisplay.textContent = storedNum + 
                selectedOperator;
                storedNum = '';

                console.log('FirstNumber' + firstNum + 'Stored' + 
                storedNum)
                console.log(selectedOperator);
                });
              }));

                //clear screen button function
                clearScreen.addEventListener('click', () => {
                currentDisplay.innerHTML = '0';
                previousDisplay.innerHTML = ' ';
                storedNum = '';
                result = '';
                selectedOperator = '';
                });


                equalsKey.addEventListener('click', function() {
                   displayResult();
                });

           function displayResult() {
             result = operate(parseFloat(firstNum), parseFloat(storedNum), selectedOperator)
             currentDisplay.textContent = result;
             previousDisplay.textContent = firstNum + ' ' + selectedOperator + ' ' + 
                storedNum;
                storedNum = result;
                console.log('First Number: ' + firstNum + ' Stored: ' + storedNum);
            }



    </script>
```

Comment: Can you please format better the code, or give as the full example code to reproduce the problem or see it better?

Comment: Done Kaneda. Hoping to get some help

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems with the management of firstNum and storedNum, your clear button was not working properly because you not clean the firstNum variable, so it leads to undefined and problems with the equations, your multiplication is with problem because your case statement is using '*' and the operator used in html is with 'x'. Another problem is doing more calculus with actual result, if you do 10 + 2 = 12 then '+ 4', lead to other problem, so in the displayResult I added in the last line a "firstNum = ''" to clear it, because it does another unnecessary computation entering in the if to displayResult again.